# WooCommerce - Display Fees per product not per Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to add a charge per shopping cart line in a WooCommerce shop. This fee is intended to change the unit price and the line sum.
This fee is not intended as a fee for shipping and grand total.
There is a service fee ($54) per basket line / per product.

For example, $ 0.81 per product plus a service-fee of $ 54 will result in $ 1.81 per product and a total of $ 94.66 at 50 pieces.

What I have so far ...

```
// Change the line total price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 'calculate_discounted_price', 10, 2 );
// Display the line total price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'display_discounted_price', 10, 2 );

function calculate_discounted_price( $price, $values ) {
    $price += 5;
    return $price;
}
function display_discounted_price( $values, $item ) {
    return wc_price( $item[ 'line_total' ] );
}
```

Many thanks for your help!